# How to show proxy authentication required dialog for MAC OS X?

Tags: macos, cocoa, proxy

I am reading the proxy credentials directly from key chain using the cocoa API SecKeychainFindInternetPassword. Sometimes I had to show below proxy authentication dialog to get credentials directly from the user in cases like the proxy password has been changed at the server side. In this case, the keychain has older credentials.

Any idea which API need to be used to prompt the below dialog?

[image]

Comment: Did you find out more Peda?